# Solving $x^2+y^2=9$, $\arctan\frac{y+2}{x+2} + \arctan\frac{y-2}{x+4} =2\arctan\frac{y}{x}$ without graphing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

The system of equations:

> $$\begin{align}
> x^2 + y^2 &= 9 \\[6pt]
> \operatorname{arctan}\frac{y+2}{x+2} + \operatorname{arctan}\frac{y-2}{x+4} &=2\,\operatorname{arctan} \frac{y}{x}
> \end{align}$$

I tried to interpret the second equation by setting $x$ and $y$ as the legs of a right triangle, but I'm still unable to solve this system of of equations geometrically. Any tips?

Comment: Geometry may not help. Taking the tangent of each side of the second equation gives $$\frac{2 (2 + 3 y + x y)}{12 + 6 x + x^2 - y^2}=\frac{2 x y}{(x - y) (x + y)}$$ so that $$6y^3+4y^2+6x^2y+12xy-27y-18=0$$ Using the first equation to eliminate $x$ gives $$160y^4+216y^3-711y^2-972y+324= 0$$ Now, solving a quartic exactly tends to be [messy business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). *Mathematica* gives these numerical solutions $$(\pm 2.9867\ldots, 0.28139\ldots) \qquad (\pm 2.1968\ldots, 2.0430\ldots)$$ along with some complex options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\arctan\dfrac{y+2}{x+2}-\arctan\dfrac yx=\arctan\dfrac  yx-\arctan\dfrac{y-2}{x+4}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{2x-2y}{x^2+y^2+2x+2y}=\dfrac{2x+4y}{x^2+y^2-2x+4y}$$

As $x^2+y^2=9$   $$\iff\dfrac{2x-2y}{9+2x+2y}=\dfrac{2x+4y}{9-2x+4y}$$

$$\iff8x^2+16y^2+54y=0\  \ \ \ (1)$$

As $x^2+y^2=9,$ WLOG $x=3\cos t,y=3\sin t$

Put these values in $(1)$ and divide both sides by $\cos^2 t$

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the equations say that the origin is at distance $3$ from $(x,y)$ and on the angular bisector of the triangle with vertices $(x,y)$, $(x+2,y+2)$, $(x+4,y-2)$.

Comment: But how do find x and y?

Comment: @HarryWang: A *geometric* solution is to use a compass to construct the circle of radius 3 around the origin and use the compass with a straightedge to construct the proper angle bisector. The intersection points give your answer. Or do you mean you want a geometric insight to solve the problem more simply and algebraically?